# Miminum values of a raster change when applying r.resample

Tags: raster, grass-gis, resolution, resampling

I am trying to aggregate a raster of a bioclimatic variable (can be downloaded here: https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V2%2FGLOBAL%2F > Climatologies > 1981-2010 > bio/ > CHELSA_bio12_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif). It has a resolution of 30" (1 x 1 km) and I want it at 5' (10 x 10 km). I import the raster, set the new resolution with `g.region -p res=0.1 raster=bio12`, and then `r.resamp.stats` should exactly do the job:

```
r.resamp.stats --o -w input=bio12 output=bio12_resampled
```

The problem is that the range of the data passes from 0(min)-65535(max) to 5-65535.
I tried to change from `method=average` to `method=median` and also to specify `quantile=0` (even tho it shouldn't be necessary, as I'm not using `method=quantile`), but the minimum value of 5 remains. I guess it has to do with the resampling of the surrounding cells: I imagine that if in 10 neighbouring cells (of 1 x 1 km) there is no cell with a value of 0, that 10 x 10 km cell will not get a 0 either... Can this be the reason (although I think it's strange to not have cells with 0 in a raster with such a fine resolution with global coverage)? Is there a better way to aggregate a raster to a coarser resolution?

Comment: Since you are taking into account 100 fine resolution cells for each low resolution result, then even a few cells of 0 in the fine res will be averaged with the other 90 or so with higher values. That one result pixel with value 5 was probably an average of several original pixels with value 0, and many surrounding pixels with values above 0. Using median or quantile won't change this. The only way to preserve the minimum value is to use the min method. (Although I'm guessing that's not what you want)

Comment: Ok, so it is how I thought. Thanks Micha :)

Answer (score 2):

There may be no zeros in your data set. When I load the raster into GRASS, I get the message 90 degree south is exceeded by 0.0166667 cells. See [link for a possible work-around](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/2757). When I load it into R, the minimum is 6.

For this and other data sets, if you want to spot 0s, try this:
Run (on the original 1 x 1 km res):

```
if(CHELSA_bio12_1981_2010_V<=10,1,null())
```

This tells you which raster cells are equal or smaller to 10.
From what I can see, this is the case in NE Africa.
Then calculate your cells with value zero:

```
if(CHELSA_bio12_1981_2010_V==0,1,null()).
```

You will probably not find any visually.

Now look for your cell with the value of 5 in your resampled raster.

```
if(res==5,1,null())
```

I see only one - within the area previously identified for all values <=10. Now within that resampled raster cell with value 5, look for the one with value 0 (2nd step). I cannot find it.

Bottom line: There are only a few or no 0s (see comment above). You may also want to look at histograms.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and it's definitely worth checking the histograms. Thanks for the answer!